# Does --css-dir always have to be relative to the project directory?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, directory, compass-sass, output-directory

I'm using compass 0.10.4

I'm running a compass command and I want it to put it's output to the
server when I run a watch instead of to the project directory.

Is there any way of specifying an absolute path instead of a path
relative to the directory you want the css output to?

I'm trying to have my compiled css output to the directory:

```
/home/leeand00/leeand00.com/wp-content/themes/coffeeSunrise
```

but instead it is being output to

```
<compass-project-dir>/home/leeand00/leeand00.com/wp-content/themes/
coffeeSunrise
```

I've tried specifying the compiled css output directory using --css-
dir on the command line.

I've also tried changing the value of css_dir to

```
/home/leeand00/leeand00.com/wp-content/wp-content/themes/coffeeSunrise
```

in config.rb and
not specifying the --css-dir argument and I get the same result.

I realize that this can be specified using ../../../ (as many times as
needed) but since I don't always know where my deployment point would
be this is sub optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Chris added this functionality to the latest build](http://groups.google.com/group/compass-users/browse_thread/thread/24670e27154e4a84/b8c041d3664646ee?hl=en#b8c041d3664646ee), but until the new version is released, you have to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Just a tip:

For windows os you can add below

```
css_path="C:/ui/myproject/css"
```